# Get date range between dates having only month and day every year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to get date range between 1st July till 31st October every year. Based on that I have to update another column.

Date field is datetime. Should be like this below:

```
Select Cash = Case When date between '1st July' and '31st October' Then (Cash * 2) End
From MytTable
```

Note: this range should work for each and every year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
SELECT Cash = CASE WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[date],112),4) 
              BETWEEN '0701' AND '1031' THEN Cash*2
              ELSE Cash END --I added this
```

Comment: what about in the case where between Nov 1 and Mar 1? ie: BETWEEN '1101' AND '0301' This doesn't work. I need a solution for this where it spans a year change but we don't want to include year as this is a recurring scheduler. maybe two betweens?  BETWEEN ('1101' AND '1231) OR ('0101' AND '0301')

Comment: @JJ_Coder4Hire If you need that, then you could ask a question and specify exactly what are your requirements (oh, and make sure to first search SO for similar questions)

Comment: @Lamak. good point. since my search query brought this back I have included the solution I just figured out. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For your case you could just use the month and make sure it falls between 7 to 10.

This is how your query will be:

```
select Cash = case when month([Date]) in (7, 8, 9, 10) then (Cash * 2) else Cash end
```

or

```
select Cash = case when month([Date])  between 7 and 10 then (Cash * 2) else Cash end
```

Comment: Thanks Vasanth.. But I need the the exact day also. If day is 4th of July to 20th of October then how should I proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me to get some themes that have been recurring scheduled by month and day. It handles spanning multiple years for example an item scheduled from Nov 1 to March 1.

My data is stored like this:

```
ThemeName, StartMonth, StartDay, EndMonth, EndDay
Christmas, 12,1,12,26
Winter, 11, 1, 3, 1
Spring, 3,1,5,1
Sports, 0,0,0,0 //continuous
```

Here is the query:

```
    SELECT
         DISTINCT ThemeName
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN EndDate < StartDate AND ((Current Between StartDate AND 1231) OR (Current Between 0101 AND EndDate) ) THEN -- span multiple year between dates
                ThemeName
            WHEN StartDate < EndDate AND Current Between StartDate AND EndDate THEN -- normal between dates
                ThemeName
            WHEN StartDate = 0 AND EndDate = 0 THEN -- continuous
                ThemeName
            ELSE
                'NG'
            END as ThemeName
        FROM (
                 SELECT
                         ThemeName, StartDate, EndDate, Current
                 FROM (     
                         SELECT
                             ThemeName,
                             CAST(Concat(LPAD(CONVERT(StartMonth , CHAR(2)),2,'0'), LPAD(CONVERT(StartDay , CHAR(2)),2,'0') ) as DECIMAL) as StartDate,
                             CAST(Concat(LPAD(CONVERT(EndMonth , CHAR(2)),2,'0'), LPAD(CONVERT(EndDay , CHAR(2)),2,'0') ) as DECIMAL) as EndDate,
                             CAST(Concat(LPAD(CONVERT(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) , CHAR(2)),2,'0'), LPAD(CONVERT(DAY(CURRENT_DATE) , CHAR(2)),2,'0') ) as DECIMAL)  as current
                         FROM
                             companythemeschedules
                         WHERE
                             companyid = 221 
                 ) a

         ) b
    ) c
    WHERE
        ThemeName != 'NG'
```

Comment: I'm not looking for an upvote. just posted my solution as my search found this page and it may help others visiting this solution

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS ONE:

```
DECLARE @DT DATE = GETUTCDATE() , @START_DATE VARCHAR(10) = '07-01' , @END_DATE VARCHAR(10) = '10-31'
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN RIGHT(@DT,5) BETWEEN  @START_DATE AND  @END_DATE
    THEN
    (CASH * 2)
    ELSE
    'NO MATCH'
END AS CASH
```